# Printf + Cat function

Tags: neo4j, cypher, printf, cat, cypher-shell

I'm currently working with Neo4j.

I want to launch a cypher script via my terminal but I would like to set parameter before launching my script.

Here my statement,

```
>printf ':param test=>'value' \n' | cat file.cypher | cypher-shell -a bolt:server -u user-p pwd --format=verbose --fail-at-end --non-interactive --debug
```

Output :

```
>org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Expected parameter(s): test
```

So I have the feeling my printf quote is not read.

Is there anybody already worked with the combination of printf and cat ?

Thank you in advance,

G.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cypher Shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell) tool has command-line options for specifying parameter values (`--param`) and input files (`-f`). You do not need to use pipes.

For example:

```
./cypher-shell -u user -p pwd -f file.cypher --param "test=>'value'"
```

Comment: I just tried it, and there is no `-f`  and `--param` arguments.

Comment: Are you using neo4j 4.0.0+?